# PHP: Safely converting the field date in mySQL from 'datetime' to 'unix timestamp' without losing data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix, datetime

## PROBLEM

I need I safely convert the date format in the mySQL database table MYTABLE from the actual **datetime** format field **date**: e.g. 2013-09-10 12:43:03, to its **unix timestamp** equivalent: 1378816983  without compromising the existing thousands of articles already in the database.

I am using PHP, mySql, Drupal.

## MY APPROACH

My steps

1. Alter the table field type from datetime to timestamp [DONE]
2. Converting the actual content type field: timestamp [DONE]
3. Converting existing article data field in 4 tables using PHP strtotime() or MYSQL: UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)

## I NEED HELP ON PT.3

A. a little help on the algorithm at the pt. 3:

e.g.

```
  loop over all 4 tables {

       - create a new column date2 of type: int (or datetime?) 
       - copy all dates from date to date2 passing them through strtotime()
       - delete column date
       - rename column date2 to column date

}
```

Comment: why would you want it?

Answer (score 0):

1. backup the table
2. check if backup is all right and safe
3. Alter the table field type from datetime to varchar
4. update table set field=unix_timestamp(field)
5. Alter the table field type from varchar to int

However I wouldn't do such a conversion at all

Comment: The unix_timestamp function accepts a datetime input, so there is no need to convert it to a varchar, so skipping that step would be safer. If something goes wrong no data has been changed.

Comment: @your-common-sense, I need to perform this change in order the article indexation to work well without performance issues, since any database query looking up entries based on this date can not be indexed (the datetime has to be converted into timestamps in the database layer).

Answer (score 0):

First off, the safest way to convert data like this is to not do it on the fly.

The first thing that I would do would be to add another column to your table. Then given that we aren't modifying existing data, I would look at using [the Unix_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) mysql function. If you are storing the data in a date datatype already, it seems that it is nice and safe for mysql to do it.

Given that, it seems to be a simple matter of running something like:

```
update MyTable set newtimeStampColumn=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(oldDateColumn);
```

and see how it works. You can then run some comparison queries to ensure that all your data has converted corectly.

Comment: could help me put this into PDO language?

Comment: @Kandinski This is something that I would be doing from a console, not from a PHP script. Having said that, if you don't have access to a console, the [alter table statement is still](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) pretty straightforward. Just write the statement and execute it. Having said that, backing up the table (via PHPMyAdmin at least) is a good idea in case you get things a little confuddled :)

Comment: this should be programmatically as the code will run on multiple websites with thousands of articles. I have re-edited my answer to clear up.